# Wildfly + PostgreSQL New missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: postgresql, jboss, dependencies, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I'm having this problem when I try to run a simple test with Arquilian.class using PostgreSQL (I could do it with H2)

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.data-source.reference-factory.java:jboss/datasources/mavenjeeTestDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.mavenjeeTestDS] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".CdiValidatorFactoryService, JBAS014799: ... and 9 more ] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#primary"] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasDAO.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.VIEW."ar.gob.ssn.apps.mavenjee.service.CuentasService".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, JBAS014799: ... and 7 more ] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart] 
  service jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/mavenjeeTestDS] 
  service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#primary" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.CuentasService.START, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test, JBAS014799: ... and 8 more ] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
```

Here is my test class, only the @deployment part

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CuentaTest {
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {

    File[] libs = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").resolve("org.postgresql:postgresql").withTransitivity().asFile();

    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addClasses(Cuenta.class, CuentasService.class, Resources.class, CuentasDAO.class)
            .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsLibraries(libs)
            // Deploy our test datasource
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-ds.xml");
}
```

I have the property **wildfly.jpa.twophasebootstrap** set in false

Please let me know if you need more .xml files in order to help me

**UPDATE 1**

I've followed the wizard of Eclipse to create an Maven Wildfly JEE7 webapp, so this is my **test-ds.xml**

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">   
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mavenjeeTestDS"
      pool-name="mavenjee-test" enabled="true" 
      use-java-context="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://XXX.XX.X.XXX:5432/xxx</connection-url>
         <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class> 
        <driver>postgresql</driver>
      <security>
         <user-name>XXX</user-name>
         <password>XXX</password>
      </security>
   </datasource>
</datasources>
```

And the **test-persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mavenjeeTestDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties> 
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="wildfly.jpa.twophasebootstrap" value="false"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**UPDATE 2**

The **pom.xml** part with the Arquillian configuration

```
<profile>           
    <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

The **arquillian.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
   <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
            <property name="jbossHome">C:/MUNDO_JAVA/Servers/wildfly-8.2.0.MavenJtaJpa</property>
        </configuration>
   </container>
</arquillian>
```

Thanks

Comment: You may need it already deployed in the server because I believe the datasource is being started before the libraries in the war are being loaded.

Comment: @LightGuard I'm using a **wildfly-arquillian-container-managed** , it starts the server and then configure the datasource, or it doesn't?

Comment: If the data source is setup in your standalone.xml file it will, otherwise no.

Comment: @LightGuard I've updated the post with more information, please let me know if it helps, thanks!

Comment: Is Arquillian downloading and unzipping Wildfly for you or is it using one already on your system?

Comment: @LightGuard Arquillian runs the Wildfly for me, I've attached the **pom.xml** to the post

Comment: How about your arquillian.xml as well?

Comment: @LightGuard I've attached the Arquillian.xml

Comment: Okay. In this situation since your JBOSS_HOME is from an existing install, add the PostgreSQL jar to the deployment directory in JBOSS_HOME and you should be good.

Comment: @LightGuard where should I put the jar? I tried in the standalone/lib/ext and in the standalone/deployments but neither of the options worked

Comment: Standalone/deployments should have worked. Is your project available to test?

Comment: @LightGuard tomorrow I'll upload the project, thank you in advance!

Comment: @LightGuard I've uploaded the project to https://github.com/villat/mavenjee , I'll wait for your answer, thanks.

Comment: I'm hearing from colleagues that -ds.xml files don't work well and your best bet is to add your datasource to the standalone.xml file and go that route.

Comment: @LightGuard it seems that the problem was the lack of the **web.xml**

Comment: Oh, okay then :) Glad you were able to figure it out.